# InitString SqlAnywhere 12 Authentication in ODBC

Tags: authentication, odbc, sqlanywhere

I have an issue with authenticating an SQLAnywhere connection set up as ODBC. For version 17 it is no problem, but with version 12 it looks like it does not authenticate. Using the 17 driver this works.

[image: Using 17 driver]

But using the version 12 driver set up the same way it does not look like it runs the command

[image]

I would like this to work without upgrading to 17 driver on the server with the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got this to work by putting the InitString in the connectonString. Where I set the DSN. Hopefully this is helpful if someone has the same issue.

[image]